# eclipse rcp : how to manage third party library?

Tags: eclipse-rcp

different plug-ins may depend on different third party libraries. for example :
plug-in A needs log4j, plug-in B needs dom4j, plug-in C needs log4j and dom4j.  what is the best practice to manage these dependencies ? If we let plug-in provider manage dependencies themself, then how can we avoid duplicated dependency ?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6545212/add-3rd-party-library-to-an-eclipse-plugin/6545353#6545353

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend using the [Eclipse Orbit project](http://www.eclipse.org/orbit/).  It provides most of the common 3rd party libraries that plugin developers want to use as OSGi bundles that can be easily installed into your target platform to develop against.  And then when you are publishing your updatesite you can add these bundles there as well.

Here is the [detailed list](http://download.eclipse.org/tools/orbit/downloads/drops/R20110523182458/) of 3rd party libraries that are available in the orbit repository.